# How to override core api interface in magento2

Tags: php-7, magento2.2

How to override the changePasswordForCustomer() in Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php .

I need to change current password as optional. How to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to do this? this seems like an odd request. Can you explain your use case better?

Comment: I need to remove current password in change password frontend section.In current password validate in \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost Controller file and its call core interface also .How to remove this.